# Trying to make a histogram with ui.Chart.image.histogram() in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram with the difference of two NDVI images from different dates, but I'm having trouble with the `ui.Chart.image.histogram()` function when I try to perform with my large asset (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/felolillorobles/Araucania_ODEPA_2019_Buffer) to obtain the histogram, equivalent to 46881041 pixels in the region.

The Error is the following:

> Error generating chart: Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 46881041, but maxPixels allows only 10000000.

The error suggests I set `MaxPixels` to a limit suitable for my computation, or set `BestEffort` to `true`. However, when I do this, I must change my original variable (`ee.Image`) to a dictionary using a reducer. This throws another error when I try to pass this new reduced variable (`ee.Dictionary`) as an input to `ui.Chart.image.histogram()`, because the function expects an `ee.Image` (like my original variable).

Another way that I've been trying this is with an `ee.Reducer.histogram()`, which allows me to use my large asset, but then, I don't know how to graph with the values contained in the resulting dictionary. Is possible to pass this dictionary object to an `ui.Chart.image.histogram()`?

Here is my script, the characters in // are other options that i was trying:

```js
// CALCULO DE DNDVI PARA SENTINEL 2A SR

//Imagen Sentinel 2A en la fecha 1
var IMGSentinel2A= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterDate ('2016-10-01', '2017-03-31')
.filterBounds (geometry)
.filterMetadata ("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",'Less_Than', 5);
var Sentinel2filtro = ee.Image(IMGSentinel2A.max());
var Sentinel2Clip = Sentinel2filtro.clip (geometry);


//BANDAS FECHA 1
var b2_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B2');
var b3_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B3');
var b4_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B4');
var b5_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B5');
var b8_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B8');
var b11_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B11');
var b12_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B12');

//Imagen Sentinel 2A en la fecha 2
var IMGSentinel2A2= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterDate ('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
.filterBounds (geometry)
.filterMetadata ("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",'Less_Than', 5);
// .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10));
 var Sentinel2filtro2 = ee.Image(IMGSentinel2A2.median());
 var Sentinel2Clip2 = Sentinel2filtro2.clip (geometry);

//BANDAS FECHA 2
var b2_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B2'); 
var b3_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B3'); 
var b4_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B4'); 
var b5_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B5'); 
var b8_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B8'); 
var b11_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B11'); 
var b12_2 = Sentinel2Clip2.select('B12'); 


//Normalized differences
var normdif1 = Sentinel2Clip.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
var normdif2 = Sentinel2Clip2.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
var dndvi = normdif1.subtract(normdif2);
print (dndvi)

//   var hist = dndvi.reduceRegion({
//   reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(),
//   geometry: geometry.geometry(),
//   scale: 10,
//   bestEffort: true,
// });

var hist = dndvi.reduceRegion({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: geometry.geometry(),
scale: 10,
bestEffort: true,
 });

 print(hist)

 // Pre-define some customization options.

var options = {
  title: 'HISTOGRAMA dNDVI',
  fontSize: 20,
  hAxis: {title: 'banda'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Frecuencia'},
  series: {
    0: {color: 'blue'},
}};
// Make the histogram, set the options.
var histogram = ui.Chart.image.histogram(hist, geometry, 30)
    .setSeriesNames(['dNDVI'])
    .setOptions(options);
    // Display the histogram.
print(histogram);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a conceptual example, based on your analysis, for generating histograms by region reduction and charting the results using either `ee.Array` or `ee.FeatureCollection` objects. I prefer these methods over charting by image histogram because they are more flexible, and in the case of the `ee.FeatureCollection` option, the histogram table can be exported as an asset, which can help when in-browser processing times out, allowing you to make histogram charts from very large regions at small scales.

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3bf352e3116afeed9c39b000c7288545)

```js
/**
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

// Define a region of interest.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-73.16191843371962, -37.8098361104156],
    [-73.16191843371962, -39.593041263040206],
    [-71.14043405871962, -39.593041263040206],
    [-71.14043405871962, -37.8098361104156]]], null, false);

// Display the region of interest.
Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry);

// Filter image collection 1 and reduce to max.
var sentinel2a = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterDate('2016-10-01', '2017-03-31')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",'Less_Than', 5)
  .max();

// Filter image collection 2 and reduce to median.
var sentinel2b = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",'Less_Than', 5)
  .median();

// Calculate difference between two dates of normalized difference (DNDVI).
var normDif1 = sentinel2a.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
var normDif2 = sentinel2b.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
var dndvi = normDif1.subtract(normDif2);

// Calculate a histogram of DNDVI using a region reduction with the
// `autoHistogram()` reducer. Note that scale is set to 1000 so that the
// operation will not time out while interactive in the Code Editor browser.
// If you have a large region and a small scale, see the below section on
// exporting the result as an asset to avoid time out errors.
var hist = dndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,
  bestEffort: true,
});

// #############################################################################
// ### HISTOGRAM CHART USING ARRAYS ###
// #############################################################################

// The result of the region reduction by `autoHistogram` is an array. Get the
// array and cast it as such for good measure.
var histArray = ee.Array(hist.get('nd'));

// Subset the values that represent the bottom of the bins and project to
// a single dimension. Result is a 1-D array.
var binBottom = histArray.slice(1, 0, 1).project([0]);

// Subset the values that represent the number of pixels per bin and project to
// a single dimension. Result is a 1-D array.
var nPixels = histArray.slice(1, 1, null).project([0]);

// Chart the two arrays using the `ui.Chart.array.values` function.
var histColumnFromArray = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array:nPixels,
  axis: 0,
  xLabels: binBottom})
  .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print(histColumnFromArray);


// #############################################################################
// ### HISTOGRAM CHART USING A FEATURE COLLECTION ###
// #############################################################################

// Cast the histogram table array as a list.
var histList = histArray.toList();

// Map over the list to create a list of features per bin and set respective
// bin bottom and number of pixels properties.
var featureList = histList.map(function(bin) {
  bin = ee.List(bin);
  var props = {
    binBottom: ee.Number(bin.get(0)),
    nPixels: ee.Number(bin.get(1))
  };
  return ee.Feature(geometry, props);
});

// Convert the feature list to a feature collection.
var featureCol = ee.FeatureCollection(featureList);

// #############################################################################
// OPTIONALLY EXPORT THE FEATURE COLLECTION

// If your region reduction times out in the browser, export the above
// feature collection as an asset. When it completes, start a new script
// that imports it and then chart it using the options following. Here is
// an example of exporting the region as an asset:

Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: featureCol,
  description: 'histogram_table',
  assetId: 'histogram_table'
});

// #############################################################################

// Chart histogram from the constructed feature collection as a line chart.
var histLineFromFc = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: featureCol,
  xProperty: 'binBottom',
  yProperties: ['nPixels']})
  .setChartType('LineChart');
print(histLineFromFc);

// Chart histogram from the constructed feature collection as a column chart.
var histColumnFromFc = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: featureCol,
  xProperty: 'binBottom',
  yProperties: ['nPixels']})
  .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print(histColumnFromFc);
```